# Is there any method to change the icons on the suggestions provided by monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider?

Tags: javascript, documentation, monaco-editor

I was trying to write **registerCompletionItemProvider** in monaco editor, and what I wanted to have was that each of the suggestions should contain a custom icon on the left. However I can't seem to find any such method provided by monaco-editor to change the default icons. I am using **0.17.1** version of **monaco-editor**.

[Suggestion Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucqup.png)

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('myCustomLang', {
  provideCompletionItems(model, position) {
    const suggestions = [
      {
        label: 'Custom suggestion',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
        insertText: 'customSuggestion',
        documentation: 'This is a custom suggestion with an image.',
        //anything for custom icons?
      }
    ];

    return { suggestions };
  }
```

Here I want the 'Custom Suggestion' to have a custom icon instead of the default one.
I tried looking at the official documentation, but could not find anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [PR raised](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/113313) to be able to customise the icons, but it was rejected. Therefore this functionality doesn't officially exist as a feature.

There are several built in icons that can be used. Monaco uses the `kind` property of [CompletionItem](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.CompletionItem.html#kind) to determine what icon to render:

```
{
    label: 'Class',
    kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Class,
    insertText: '"Class":',
    range: range,
}
```

The possible values can be seen [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/enums/languages.CompletionItemKind.html).

If none of these are suitable and you want to use your own icons, you can define the following CSS. The selector should be in the format `.codicon-symbol-xxxx:before` (for example, `.codicon-symbol-function` will override the icons for completion items of type `monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function`):

```
.codicon-symbol-function:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAv0lEQVQ4ja1SwQ3CMAy8ov7oAkzAAH3x8odZUjFR1czSz714dQAmYIH2hxQeVaKQOCAKJ1myYp99tlM550DSYSPq4BxOasLjfoXITY2RR+zSx35c0I+L3s7a1SJkBS7nfZlszGpRkVrPLiDprip4C6/gUwF1jJgY+dXfzigiagJJNNKosZlzPgJJkFQJdupgp05X4MleSex7smmHrOh3V1DwokBEgvx0J6YdgvxYSfaRSstMiR4/n7FybjMXAPAE2d9Nr9xjGbYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
}
```

In this example we overwrite the icon for suggestions of type `monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function` with a base64 image.

[This demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.38.0#XQAAAALbFAAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscxc-nHMpi2lRCF4_h_37ShtCqrLqM_tf7mf2Ur0sz058AwsV0SGtfZSZ_Un5IXrnxSEs4EyUQU7SUzir5J3a63i1ippeSyow3MUSFqHQeXHnNb990qn8o1THUhRDaME-XOv2dzpF43e8MuAEPhRdeka7rLDmA7A1h5mYy2B0VbsX2QN_d9bJMBoWIChfeFQSdllCfbQRuLvMgT_IfqQfa9MrCUfFi5ZQwoP3yYKn4ctRIK9jOt7mPYh5gJ4wbWewU-lA6XeNUYMHroh5ahih8qovjiuXVDO4haaJhm77pGBOgB7LCBVWAkDce_7pS8b8DEvjyuCG8e9P0w85bSJAelqhUeCWOyLbhUi2upbbjKqvgWyiB8SfimxJh_0AGjZa5olC__Pd2ZPrRitYs9EeyZ5lrnXAoOuSsvGndYFZtjm1wHxco8IW2t991nKvdNJf-XscpMWzUeuW9YPBs1tyFWGZniDqCdObjvDQLdz4-4uZD5yVjTEXTtz9wHjXw3Cu1pdC3bMuXLx9iyIvNDv335YArU9pvElgLUtABj1hVSJXXpvtgbYznubqHdpsaZhx54KEjoMwR6Ukw4-O9knWVsDOQKG5oPUjMioVYc6trZtJOOm0xestJP8HSWBk84CWo_xm2TcvaoO9sl9pF9Ip5g4FT8G_f35LMxIpDMhCoTPeo7Et4ZK_7N_cjCJBqO-NExO9VMUh_pcq5rJL1i81_gBa9J5un8OPufo-35LiF-3GtBX7bxsJnm5gSUAHgoVYEGjPrEI_jWilU5oQoyqChUxkvIxSUjye2l7F_4sfiV-D8MgI4PLoS7dtZEzNXzL5ZJK-_ywyoxQmnlmXTOhwiRicmwxpZO1SuhbfEDq18mwBVK6zSVj95kZozaM2-V4sT4I_Jjiu905kd8p5IQaMkfvECv6JFMY8AGkl4sC3U2G1BH011FngXaHFSTKMAViKdAWeLJkPNzmNMi9hFE--6Gs4nt8wVUEqofgQEkk6lzMO1bHm0OwZVFESyPhxeY1teFg7LB6VTDgqIlfjaAcNr9uRgK2pwVC_oRkGWS_ozFHloA1Ag5ITQIItFDClTtSk_rFPiSdGVV2xtK2q93_fk17WKGm76k3HPSmyuXR3mhih7jfTIHRUWQZcmDJ1pluznpluPTnllvYEeVyaBM6rlbPpJRff7S7FVDc_VoJ9gKWW9E-JbPvJCvN-GGKq_BnJjtt9-UCYP0nvP95ujc27MX7hsTDjXAq-opmqB4cYdv_ykNXWld2zomfaxr-MhHLAmqwOFphDLnKFA7uDeSIw415RlpWEuHWAMFDSQ-WFw-KMh6-Mh13DnFaFy5vKFuvSaStlewU44mVdK0fLOSwFuIP17F0pOoblsQXkdWI-QHsof9VIQt_e7EfiNUTKzVkeJsjhZXxT-N1ZwDOHdTRahONWqg3JrJOMvGhd72OskL0-FFxynHfIK6FBjcjTKctnzmKfd1D6LHLt16MDdmI282HlfrbrxCZqVB87V_7a24-lOKP4KAVBlw-GuWGZtnybrzNOTxXforFdfMs8EU4dmukKZIsuqdIpE0z7D5pZ2s0GwNPakwGlaSXLkukZTw54Cu9_UsaKzHPIfNwMS2ZK2btk1d3lT6lA4RyfrM8K5PArmr6Gsm3zqCvNHhRr4ZVZSm3iFG2uo-nVY8YfYHpbHrfOkHbH8aomiGEXL_j_3aOYl1rOpoWXsIFQPGuDUfa78SQAQzHvRnktY7mg3Dd0mpSUE3yRmndLJUMu2GwRXF09c00oPE4dHbmUvyP15eBS_svVjkvemcK9nDtw8X_-tEyYc) shows each of the different default icons and one custom icon. Note: I've overridden the `function` icon with a custom icon, so if you type `f` in the editor, you should see a suggestion `Function` with the custom icon.